# Order of parameters in QGIS 3.6 graphical modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-3

When using graphical modeler in QGIS 3.6 I have added additional parameters to the model inputs for the buffer tool.

The model looks like this:

[image]

When running the tool the order of the parameters in the resultant window do not follow the order parameters were added. They appear to be listed alphabetically:

[image]

I can change this quite easily by exporting the model as a Python script (as per [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322831/sort-inputs-parameters-in-qgis-modeler?rq=1)) and changing the order of the input parameters there:

[image]

This means my model is a now a Python script rather than a .model3 file. Is there any way to change the order of parameters through graphical modeler. Or alternatively is there a way to save a Python script as a .model3 file?

Comment: they will apear in the order of addition to the modell.

Comment: After much testing I've found this not to be true in QGIS 3.6.2 nor 3.4

Comment: This is a subject of hot debate and there is no current logical method to change the order in the GUI. However, this answer on another question found a great work around which I now use all the time. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316901/97475

Comment: Thanks @AWGIS. If you can provide a brief overview of the method and link to that question in an answer I'll accept. I've been experimenting and it works well as a wrokaround.

Comment: @AWGIS where does the "hot debate" take place? I've searched the QGIS issues on GitHub but I didn't find anything related to the order of the inputs in the GUI.

Comment: @AWGIS, nevermind, reordering inputs is now possible with QGIS 3.14, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377357/105333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently an intuitive method to achieve this in the Graphical Modeler GUI. A recent answer on another question linked [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316901/97475) gave a great work-around that involves numbering the inputs in chronological order to act as Psuedo IDs. You can then rename the inputs after this to whatever you would like.

If you are editing an existing model then you need to create a new copy of the input parameter, give it an appropriate Psuedo ID then delete the existing input.